# Is there any way to append text to files outside the Shortcuts directory via iOS Shortcuts.app?

Tags: shortcuts-app

I would like to create a shortcut (in the Shortcuts app) to append text to a csv file.

The file already exists. For a variety of reasons I don't want to move the file from its current location to `iCloud Drive/Shortcuts` — not least because this would cause some disruption to existing workflows and file sharing, and negate any of the time saving benefit of the shortcut.

The Shortcuts app is obviously sandboxed to `iCloud Drive/Shortcuts`. But is there a way to safely work within this restriction while still appending text to files outside the Shortcuts directory?

I have had a look at aliasing/ symlinking the file, and have also considered scripting. But so far have not found a workable solution.

I'm wondering of there is any clever way to maintain all of the safety and benefit that Shortcuts.app's sandboxed approach offers, while still allowing explicitly defined and approved files/ locations to be modified.

(I realise that I could configure the shortcut to have the user select the file each time the shortcut runs, but as the file location will never change and I will be the only person using this shortcut, I'd prefer to streamline this step.)

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: This is al old post... but I just checked, you can append to any file on macOS and iOS. The problem with that approach is that the file exists only in a given machine (I guess, haven't tried it).